# Do not refresh page on submit PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to achieve that when I click on submit button, it doesn't refresh the page.
My submit button only calls set of codes if is submitted.
But when it is submitted, it refreshes the page and my variables lose its values.

I know this can be achieved with java-script or ajax but this is where I have no knowledge yet. Need to start learning it.
I have tried to use some other suggestion with JavaScript but it didn't work for me as the JavaScript code was build for most advance form not only one submit button.

My Button:

```
  <form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='post'>
      <input type='submit'  class='submit' name='confirm_points' value='Confirm Points' />
  </form>";
```

My code which executes when submit button is pressed:

```
if(isset(&_POST['confirm_points'])) {
    // my code is here
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Marcel, do you know how to use jQuery?

Comment: You have to AJAX for what you want. It's easy with jQuery as @Makville mentioned.

Comment: @Makville - Jquery only implementing as I am learning it at the moment do do something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['points'])) {
    echo "I'm AJAX and I have " . $_POST['points'];
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="points" placeholder="Some data" value="25 points"/>
    <input type='submit'  class='submit' name='confirm_points' value='Confirm Points' />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page with the form that should submit by ajax

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="my-form">
            <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#my-form').submit(function (e) {
                    var $data = $(this).serialize();
                    var $url = 'path_to_processing_script';
                    $.post($url, $data, function ($response, $status ) {
                        if ( $status == 'success' ) {
                             alert($response);
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The processing script

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Makville... it works... I have also tried switchers code and it works too...

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First to stop refreshing, change your form header to:

```
<form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='post' onsubmit="javascript:return false;" id="myform">
```

Next, to submit form using ajax:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(){
        var elem1=$("#elem1").val(); //get values of inputs for validation
        if(elem1.length<5){alert("Length too short!");}//Sample Validation
        else{
            $.ajax({
                url:"verify.php",//link to your submission page
                type:"post", //change to your needs
                data:{"elem1":elem1}, //add all variable
                success:function(response){alert(response);} //Manage Response
            });
    });
});
</script>
```